# BUILD_BUG_ON(dt_virt_base % SZ_2M) gives me error when NR_CPUS is reduced to 2

Tags: linux, gcc, build, linux-kernel, arm64

When I set NR_CPUS to 2, I get this error while building linux-5.10.0rc (when NR_CPUS is 4, it does not).

> arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c: In function 'fixmap_remap_fdt':
> ././include/linux/compiler_types.h:315:38: error: call to
> '__compiletime_assert_404' declared with attribute error: BUILD_BUG_ON
> failed: dt_virt_base % SZ_2M   315 |  _compiletime_assert(condition,
> msg, _*compiletime_assert*, **COUNTER**)
> |                                      ^

The function fixmap_remap_fdt looks like this and the line `BUILD_BUG_ON(dt_virt_base % SZ_2M);` seems to generate error.

```
void *__init fixmap_remap_fdt(phys_addr_t dt_phys, int *size, pgprot_t prot)
{
    const u64 dt_virt_base = __fix_to_virt(FIX_FDT);
    int offset;
    void *dt_virt;

    /*
     * skip some comments
     */
    BUILD_BUG_ON(MIN_FDT_ALIGN < 8);
    if (!dt_phys || dt_phys % MIN_FDT_ALIGN)
        return NULL;

    /*
     * skip (some comments)
     */
    BUILD_BUG_ON(dt_virt_base % SZ_2M);      // <=== line generating error

    BUILD_BUG_ON(__fix_to_virt(FIX_FDT_END) >> SWAPPER_TABLE_SHIFT !=
             __fix_to_virt(FIX_BTMAP_BEGIN) >> SWAPPER_TABLE_SHIFT);
```

I know this BUILD_BUG_ON is supposed to generate error when some condition is true during build time and this is possible because some conditions can be known at build time. But in this case, this dt_virt_base is some virtual address of fixmap (predefined virtual addresses for special purposes in kernel) and it is aligned to SZ_2M. See the definition in arch/arm64/include/asm/fixmap.h.

```
enum fixed_addresses {
    FIX_HOLE,

    /*
     * Reserve a virtual window for the FDT that is 2 MB larger than the
     * maximum supported size, and put it at the top of the fixmap region.
     * The additional space ensures that any FDT that does not exceed
     * MAX_FDT_SIZE can be mapped regardless of whether it crosses any
     * 2 MB alignment boundaries. 
     * 
     * Keep this at the top so it remains 2 MB aligned.
     */
#define FIX_FDT_SIZE        (MAX_FDT_SIZE + SZ_2M)
    FIX_FDT_END,
    FIX_FDT = FIX_FDT_END + FIX_FDT_SIZE / PAGE_SIZE - 1,

    FIX_EARLYCON_MEM_BASE,
    FIX_TEXT_POKE0,
```

And this indexs (enum type) means number of pages from the fixmap top virtual address. So if we have this index, we can get the virtual address. __fix_to_virt is defined in include/asm-generic/fixmap.h as below.

```
#define __fix_to_virt(x)    (FIXADDR_TOP - ((x) << PAGE_SHIFT))
```

So, when I reduce NR_CPUS from 4 to 2, I get this build time compile error. But I can't understand why this is giving me the error. Could anyone tell me what is causing the error?

Comment: That seems unusual behavior. It should only produce a compile time error if the condition is known to be true of if the compiler cannot determine that the condition is false at compile time. (Regarding the compile time test, the use of a `const` variable in the condition is slightly unusual.) Does the problem persist after a `make clean`?.

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference, but replacing `BUILD_BUG_ON(dt_virt_base % SZ_2M);` with `BUILD_BUG_ON(__fix_to_virt(FIX_FDT) % SZ_2M);` would be a slightly safer way to write the test since it is definitely a compile-time constant and not using a `const` auto variable initialized to a compile-time constant.

Comment: @IanAbbott Hi, your suggestion (`BUILD_BUG_ON(__fix_to_virt(FIX_FDT) % SZ_2M);` works!  Will you put an answer with this and hopefully with a little explanation so that I can choose? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps it was a fluke. What happens if you change it back to `BUILD_BUG_ON(dt_virt_base % SZ_2M);` and run `make` again?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have added `#pragma GCC push_options` and `#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")` before the function fixmap_remap_fdt and `#pragma GCC pop_options` after it. (making the function not optimized for debugging). Without this O0 option, it compiles ok with the original code(dt_virt_base % SZ_2M). But with this option, the original code generates above mentioned build error. If I change the option to `O1`, the original code builds ok. Maybe the BUILD_BUG_ON cannot apply the optimization correctly? Thanks for further leading me to this observation..